# How the values in word2vec embedding are created for each word

Tags: self-study, neural-networks, backpropagation, word-embeddings, word2vec

I was going through word2vec materials from Andrew Ng's course and below is what i understood.

-> **Step1**

- A matrix of shape embedding_size*number_of_unique_words is created and populated with random decimal values

-> **Step2**

- For each word, one hot encoded array of size number_of_unique_words*1 is created.
- We also pull the matrix embedding_size*1 from the matrix created in previous step.
- Multplied through matrix multiplication with the matrix created in matrix created in both the previuos step. This gives an array of shape embedding_size*1.

-> **Step3**

- For each target word, final embedding created in step2 is extracted for context words and fed into hidden layer and in the output layer we predict the wprd.

**The challenge i am facing** is i am unable to find a clue how embedding matrix is updated. For example, if there are 10000 unique words and 200 is embedding size, this embedding after training process will have some decimal value in each cell of the matrix. So for a particular word lets say `happy`, we can have an array of sze 200 which will have some decimal values `[0.0123,-0.42,......,0.036]`

**So my question is how this matrix is created?**

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backpropagation

Comment: https://github.com/bollu/bollu.github.io "Everything you know about word2vec is wrong."

Comment: @Sycorax, thanks for both the links, the first link i understand that its because of backpropagation, but not some solid explanation. Second link already states what i feared so far, but falls short of explaining the correct approach in theoritical terms.

Comment: Are you asking for an explanation of how back-propagation works in the case of word2vec? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, since it's clear that matrix learns it's values through backpropagation. Since you already pointed out that there are too many incorrect explanations. Can you suggest a correct explanation?

Comment: So, the answer to your question is "ordinary backprop" (chain rule differentiation) with the additional detail that the source and context words are maintained as separate matrices, as described in the second link. We have many questions applying backprop and explaining how to do it in detail, so you just apply the general method to word2vec.